# Rewriting message header To: field when sending email

Tags: postfix, smtp

I am configuring an SMTP server with Postfix (v3.7.3) for local (i.e. host only) mail sending on openSUSE 15.5 Leap.

What I would like is to send messages to local "users" (there is no real user on that host) like root, redirect those mails to some real address or addresses and see the correct addresses in the `To:` field of the message header (i.e. the real recipients).

`main.cf` is configured with:

```ini
...
myorigin = $myhostname
virtual_alias_maps = lmdb:/etc/postfix/virtual
smtp_header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks
...
```

In `/etc/postfix/virtual`, I have setup my redirection:

```
root    user1@domain.tld, user2@domain.tld
```

I should probably do this with `alias_maps` using `/etc/aliases`, but by default, `local` is commented/disabled in `master.cf` so I went with virtual.

In `smtp_headers_checks`, I have:

```
/^To:.*root@myhost.domain.tld.*/  REPLACE To: user1@domain.tld, user2@domain.tld
```

Now, I find this error prone and I feel I am not doing it the proper way. Error prone because I have to keep `virtual` and `smtp_headers_check` in sync manually. So when someone modifies one file, he should also remember to modify the other file.
Experience tells me: that will not happen.

If I disable `smtp_header_checks`, the message I receive has its header `To:` set to root@myhost.domain.tld, which I don't want: I want the recipients to know to whom the message was delivered.

However, I want to keep the `From:` field to root@myhost.domain.tld (to identify who/what sent that message from what host). Which is why I am not using other replacements options (I don't remember what I have tried, I think `canonical_maps`, also tried to set `myorigin` to something else, etc...) as they replace both fields (`From:` and `To:`).

So my question is is there a better/proper way to achieve what I have done with a single file saying messages to root (or root@myhost.domain.tld) shall be sent to user1@domain.tld and user2@domain.tld with the `To:` message header field replaced with those addresses and not the `From:` ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for [`canonical_maps`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#canonical_maps)?

> Optional address mapping lookup tables for message **headers and envelopes**. The mapping is applied to both sender and recipient addresses, in both envelopes and in headers, as controlled with the [`canonical_classes`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#canonical_classes) parameter. This is typically used to clean up dirty addresses from legacy mail systems, or to replace login names by `Firstname.Lastname`. The table format and lookups are documented in [canonical(5)](https://www.postfix.org/canonical.5.html). For an overview of Postfix address manipulations see the [ADDRESS_REWRITING_README](https://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html) document.

As the format for `canonical_maps` is the same as for `virtual_alias_maps`, you might use the same file, e.g.,

```
canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

If you only want to rewrite addresses in the `To:` header, you could limit it with:

```
canonical_classes = header_recipient
```

Comment: I liked the idea very much and I tried it. Unfortunately, now I remember I tried something similar with `canonical_xx`, and it only shows one of the two users defined in `virtual`. 